# JSON Array not filtering or searching but no error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, search, filter

My JQuery code is not filtering or searching the JSON array, however, it is pretty much the same code on w3schools. But I am not getting any error. Is there a way to get this to work?

I needed it to search through the JSON array and return the values.

////////////////////////////////////////////

The JSON:

```
[
 {
   "ID": 1,
   "Station": "Carmichael Rd.",
   "Address": "54 Myers Rd.",
   "Monthly_CStore_Sales": "120,000",
   "Operator": "Michael Sears",
   "Top_SKU": "Hotdogs"
 },
 {
   "ID": 2,
   "Station": "Baillou Hill",
   "Address": "564 Jackson Ave.",
   "Monthly_CStore_Sales": "89000",
   "Operator": "Sarah Pikes",
   "Top_SKU": "Patties"
 },
 {
   "ID": 3,
   "Station": "Oakesfield",
   "Address": "42 Peterson St.",
   "Monthly_CStore_Sales": "150000",
   "Operator": "Yolanda Gray",
   "Top_SKU": "Chicken"
 },
 ]
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
        <body>
         <p><br></br></p>
          <div class="container">
          <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search"></div></br>
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"></table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Station</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Monthly_CStore_Sales</th>
                <th>Operator</th>
                <th>Top_SKU</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <script>
        $('#search').keydown(function(){
          $.getJSON("smallData.json",function(data){
            var search = $('#search').val();
            var regex = new RegExp(search,'i');
            var output;
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
            if((val.ID.toString().search(regex) != -1)  || (val.Station.toString().search(regex) != -1)){
                output += "<tr>";
                output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.ID+"</td>";
                output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.Station+"</td>";
                output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.Address+"</td>";
                output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.Monthly_CStore_Sales+"</td>";
                output += "<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.Top_SKU+"</td>";
                output += "</tr>";
              }
            });
            $('tbody').html(output);
            });
          })

      </script>
```

Comment: You've got an extra closing bracket at the end of the array. Also you should separate the HTML from the Javascript, it's a bit hard to look at right now.

Comment: @JohnKrakov I made some changes as was suggested by you and RugerSR9, however, the extra closing bracket is a mistake....but the code still does not work. Can you post it in your editor and see if you're getting any errors please.

Comment: also there is an extra comma behind the ID 3

Comment: Add a debug; line before the $.getJSON and step through it or do a console.log(output) and make sure you are getting data and using the correct parameters to access the data.